# ClientContext object not updating properly

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

```
ClientContext cl = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("http://" + "mysharepoint" + "/" + SubWeb);
System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypass", "ntuni");

cl.Credentials = cred;

ListItemCollection result;
List qrtList = cl.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(QRT_LIST_NAME);
result = qrtList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
cl.Load(result);
cl.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem item in result)
{
    if (item.FieldValues["UniqueId"].ToString() == QrtId)
    {

        item.FieldValues["R_x00e9_ponse"] = r.ResponseTxt;
        item.Update();
        qrtList.Update();        
    }
}

cl.ExecuteQuery();
```

My object doesnt update once i visite the sharepoint for some reason. This is wraped around a try catch and nothing gets caught. Halp ? Thanks !

ps: Adding new item works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you add items using your app then modify them in sharepoint...You need to reload your listitems/list after because you have an outdated version of your list

...Your question need some clarification on :

1.what needs to be update

2.what are you doing to get to this